# Html 5 video stop event

Tags: javascript, html, video

Im green with JS, bit i would like to implement to my website html 5 video.

video code looks like this

```
<video id="myvideo" style=width:600px; height:550px controls>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

I would like to make video pasue on 15 second and trigger an event
Now my event is on button
 button code

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Watch</button>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        RC_STARTGATE();
    }
</script>
```

Edit: Button is temporary solution.  I would like to remove button and something like this:
Video starts=> after 15 seconds it pauses=> and triggers same event as button did  RC_STARTGATE().

Edit 2: Great! now i need to get button removed and start timeout when video starts.

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

function myFunction(){
    vid.play();

    setTimeout(function(){
        vid.pause();
    }, 15000); //

setTimeout(function(){
        RC_STARTGATE();
    }, 15000); //
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the button is clicked, the video starts playing, and after 15 seconds you want it stopped?

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myvideo");

function myFunction(){
    vid.play();

    setTimeout(function(){
        vid.pause();
    }, 15000); //15 second timeout in milliseconds
}
```

**EDIT 2**

To remove the button, add an id (`<button id="mybtn">`) so you can reference and remove it like this:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("mybtn");
btn.parentElement.removeChild(btn);
```

Comment: Thx man. Can now it be like in main post in edit 2 description?